# VueJs - Vuex - Change a state

Tags: vue.js, web, vuetify.js, vuex

i am new to VueJS and Vuex and add Vuex to my project.

I want to change the state "mode" to "" (A blank String) with a switch component from Vuetify.

This is my store/index.js file:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    mode: 'dark',
  },
  mutations: {
    change (state) {
      state.mode += '';
    }
  },
})
```

This is my Vue Code (Only snippets, not the whole code)

```
<v-switch
          v-model="switchLightDark"
          :label="`Dark / Light Mode: ${switchLightDark.toString()}`"
        ></v-switch>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      switchLightDark: true,
    }
  },
  watch : {
    switchLightDark(newValue) {
      this.$store.commit('change');
      console.log(newValue);
    }
  }
    
}
</script>
```

Is this the right method to do this? Or is a easier way to make this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the  `state.mode += '';` doesn't change any thing in the state, it just add an empty string the right way is to mutate it using assignment `=` using the payload:

```
this.$store.commit('change', newValue?'light':'dark');
```

then inside the mutation :

```
  mutations: {
    change (state, mode) {
      state.mode =mode;
    }
  },
```